# Detect Change event instantly

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect textbox change event from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786799/how-to-detect-textbox-change-event-from-javascript)

How I can detect inserted value to text field immediately after inserting? `change` event rises only after focus lost, `keyPress, keyUp, keyDown`, etc can't help me, because new values are inserted from barcode scanner(it don't rises this keyboard events). Only using Timer and periodically check values in text field?

Comment: have you try `onchange` event?

Comment: It is not simple, try using some pre-made script, like http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event

Comment: It's really doesn't work! I can't believe this... it's very interesting to know. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe DOMSubtreeModified works for this too. But be sure to check if that event exists in the browser and provide an alternative if not.

Comment: not sure but maybe you can use Object.Watch with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `oninput` event. It will trigger whenever an input is made in the field.

For more information, I'll get a quote from this blog: http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript (written by [@AndyE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e))

> *Talking about onkeydown and timers...*
>
> However, this still doesn’t deal with input that doesn’t involve a keyboard. What other types of input? How about context menu actions; cut, paste, undo and redo?   Drag and drop?  There have been events to handle some other kinds of input change for a while – several browsers support the onpaste, oncut and oncopy events – but they’re non-standard and some vendors are just too stubborn to implement them.
>
> Enter the HTML 5 event, oninput.

For a cross-browser jQuery plugin, you can take a look at this one (same author): http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event

Answer (score 0):

You mean this http://jsfiddle.net/SP69J/10/

The function

```
$(document).ready(check);
  var previousvalue="";
function check(){
var val=$("#inputcontrol").val();
var interval;

 interval = window.clearInterval(interval); 
    if(val!=previousvalue){
    alert("value changed");
        previousvalue=$("#inputcontrol").val();
    }        
 interval = window.setInterval(check, 500);    
}​
```

Set the interval as per your need.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputcontrol">​
```