# Javascript function called when textboxes are filled with data

Tags: javascript, ajax

How would one make a javascript function which constantly checks to see if the user has input data into one or more textboxes?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786799/how-to-detect-textbox-change-event-from-javascript is probably of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `setInterval`. You should use `onchange` event.

See http://jsfiddle.net/QwBU8/

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onchange=change;
document.getElementById('mytextarea').onchange=change;
function change(e){
    if(!e){e=window.event;}
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+='Element with id "'+this.id+'" has changed\n';  
}
```

But be aware that this event isn't fired at the moment that the textbox is modified; it is fired when it loses focus (only if it has changed, of course).

If you want to fire the event each time is modified you can use `oninput` (but it's not supported by all browsers).

But avoid using `setInterval`, it eats up a lot of resources. Imagine that you have 30 tabs opened in your browser, and all of them have a different `setInterval`. The browser will freeze!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval) function to execute some function at regular intervals:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // do your check here => this will run every second
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things, run a function with `setInterval` which checks for the values of the textarea periodically, or bind a combination of `mousedown`,`keydown`,`keyup`,`keypress` and `keyup` events to detect every possible way of inputting data, then comparing the current length of the textarea's text with the last value (0, initially) to see whether there's a change. If there is, call the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setInterval(function() {
   if(($('#textbox').val() != "")){
        //do something  or call function
}
else{
       // do something or call function    
}

}, 1000);
```