# jQuery dynamically generated textbox change event

Tags: jquery, html

How to bind change event to dynamically generated textbox?

```
$("#searchtext").change(function()
{
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

$("#textbox1").live('change', function(){
    value = $("#textbox1").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Both of the above functions are not working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `keyup` or `focus` event instead of `change`

Comment: .live() is deprecated since version 1.7, what is your jQuery version ?

Comment: Hope this will help you out

[Onchange][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5787218/2219371

Comment: may be because - you can see at least 3 questions similar to this on SO for every day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live()` since `live()` is deprecated since version `1.7`:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#textbox1', function() {
    value = $("#textbox1").val();   
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: working bt not on textchange. its showing popup when textbox goes out of focus

Comment: Use `keydown()` instead of `change()` event.

Comment: no it will not help. i want like google search. user types and value should be captured